# How to hide a particular row button in Dynamic UITableViewCell in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I have implemented a Dynamic TableView, Textfield and Buttons. My problem is, when I hide the button in the first row of my `UITableViewCell`, the other five rows of cell button also get hidden.

Can any one suggest a solution for this issue?

I have tried below code..

```
ladiesdetails=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"2",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0", nil];



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 6;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell1";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[passengerdetailcell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
if([[ladiesdetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]==2)
{
cell.malebutton.hidden=yes;
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: when you hide malebutton at `indexPath.row==2` then you have to shown for other indexpath also. write `hidden=no;` in else part of if condition and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
bool flag = ([[ladiesdetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue] == 2)
cell.malebutton.hidden = flag
```

Comment: Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the else condition and make the button visible in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. If you have any other condition to show add that as well.

```
if([[ladiesdetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue] == 2) {
   cell.malebutton.hidden = YES;
} else {
   cell.malebutton.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of cell reuse , you use allocate the cell like below one .

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 6;
    }
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        PassengerDetailTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PassengerDetailCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if([[self.ladiesdetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]==2)
        {
            cell.maleButton.hidden = TRUE;
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: PassengerDetailTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PassengerDetailCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    this line show an error like NSInternalConsistencyyException:unable to dequeue the cell..Why this error

Comment: check whether you import correct header and name of the class are Same , my code would have class naming different